# Sum range with dynamic row on google sheet column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to sum a trying column,
I need the row in the range to be dynamic
I have tried

```
=sum($B$9:CONCAT("B", ROW()))
```

and then drag it but I'm getting an error,
I also tried with the address and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheets have a simple way to express this sort of thing: [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/). Try this in cell C9:

`=sum(B$9:B9)`

Then drag down the formula cell to extend it to additional rows.

Comment: is there a way to apply this dynamically to the conditional formatting for an entire column without using the drag option?

Comment: @d0rf47 This answer is not about conditional formatting. Please post a [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).